# Column from powershell query with array list of servers is not exporting properly to csv

Tags: powershell, csv

need some help with this bit of code. So I have got some powershell that is called from a bit of code as below:

```
powershell -file "E:\crs\shared\utils\EventViewerExport\EventViewerExport.ps1" "BAUT101,BAUT103,BAUT105,BAUT106,BAUT107,BAUT108,BAUT109,BAUT010"
```

The powershell code that the above calls is below:

```
#List of servers: 
$ArraySvr = $args[0].split(",") ;

foreach ($Server in $ArraySvr){
$args = @{}
$args.Add("StartTime", ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-160)))
$args.Add("EndTime", (Get-Date))
$args.Add("LogName", "System")
$args.Add("ID",7001)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $args -ComputerName $Server | select MachineName,LogName,LevelDisplayName,TimeCreated,ProviderName,ID,@{n='Message';e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Log.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}} | export-csv -Delimiter '|' -Path  E:\crs\shared\utils\EventViewerExport\EventViewerExportFile.csv -Append -Force
}
```

The script is almost 100% perfect, except the "Message" column isn't pulling through the the CSV file while its in the foreach function.

My csv file looks like this:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
"MachineName"|"LogName"|"LevelDisplayName"|"TimeCreated"|"ProviderName"|"Id"|"Message"
"BAUT101.compname.adp"|"System"|"Information"|"03/03/2022 18:03:15"|"Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon"|"7001"|
```

**However** the Message column does pull through when I take out the foreach function, as below:

```
$args = @{}
$args.Add("StartTime", ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-160)))
$args.Add("EndTime", (Get-Date))
$args.Add("LogName", "System")
$args.Add("ID",7001)
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $args -ComputerName 'BAUT101' | select MachineName,LogName,LevelDisplayName,TimeCreated,ProviderName,ID,@{n='Message';e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Log.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}} | export-csv -Delimiter '|' -Path  E:\crs\shared\utils\EventViewerExport\EventViewerExportFile.csv -Append -Force
```

By running this set of code with the foreach function, I get the correct csv export:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord
"MachineName"|"LogName"|"LevelDisplayName"|"TimeCreated"|"ProviderName"|"Id"|"Message"
"BAUT101.compname.adp"|"System"|"Information"|"03/03/2022 18:03:15"|"Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon"|"7001"|"compname\djgood"
```

Does anyone know why on earth the Message column won't export when I'm running the powershell with an array of servers, but it will when I query a specific computer name?

Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `$Log.ReplacementStrings[1]` to `$_.ReplacementStrings[1]`

Comment: Although $Log did need changing, that didn't help the issue. The message column still doesn't pull through to csv after changing to $_.

Comment: That makes sense if the user accounts in question are _local accounts_ - the SID can only be translated by a machine that actually recognizes it, so you'll need to execute the `Translate()` call _on the server where the event originated_.

Comment: Yeah I'm querying domain user accounts, not local accounts. How would I execute the Translate() if I am doing the powershell script remotely with the array of servers?